# Waiting time for specific event in multiple independent poisson processes

Tags: exponential-distribution, poisson-process

If I have $n$ independent Poisson processes with rates $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i = r_{tot}$, the expected time until any event occurs is $\frac{1}{r_{tot}}$. If I am interested in the expected time until event $k$ happens, is this just going to be $\frac{1}{r_k}$ (and still following an $Exp(r_k)$ distribution) as the Poisson processes are independent? Or does it change now that there are other events happening as well? I suspect by the very nature of the Poisson processes being independent that the former is true, but I just want to make sure I'm thinking along the right lines.

Comment: It changes. The time until the first occurs has an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{r_{tot}}$.  By the memoryless property, the time until the kth occurs is the sum of k iid exponential random variables with that mean. Therefore, the distribution of the time to the kth event has a Gamma distribution and the expected value of the time to the kth event is $\frac{k}{r_{tot}}$.

Comment: @JohnL Just to clarify, I mean the event corresponding to rate k, not the kth event to take place. So it could be the first event, it could be the 100th event - I just want the distribution of waiting times for that specific event.

Comment: I see. The waiting time until the first event of the kth Poisson process occurs is still Exponential and does not depend on when the events in the other processes occurs.